# Showing parameters invalid while trying to interact with contract

Tags: tezos-client, tezos-base

[image]

It was working fine a day back with the same input but it is showing this error pls help to solve this problem

my deployed contract
https://better-call.dev/ghostnet/KT1GdyzuivqC7eng11H9iyaABLAp3eEsr8cF/interact/addUserTowhiteList

Answer (score 0):

There's a high chance it's a beacon issue, can you please try to clear the localstorage and try again? Usually, it's F12 -> Application -> Local Storage -> better-call.dev -> Right click -> Clear -> Ctrl + f5